# Trouble with nested for loops C++ (beginner)

Tags: c++

So I'm starting out practicing some code and wanted to create a Z shape using "X" in a 7x7 like grid.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing?? Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    
    string x = "X";
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++){
            if((i = 0) || (i = 6)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else if((i = 1) && (j = 5)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else if((i = 2) && (j = 4)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else if((i = 3) && (j = 3)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else if((i = 4) && (j = 2)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else if((i = 5) && (j = 1)){
                cout<<x;
            }
            else{
                cout<<" ";  
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    
    return 0;
     
}
```

Comment: All your `i = 0` (and similar expressions) in the `if` statements should be `i == 0`. The `=` operator is *assignment*; `==` is for comparisons.

Comment: Typo? `if((i = 0) || (i = 6))` (and all other `if` statements) `=` is an assignment. Did you mean to use `==`, which is operator, that compares to values if they are equal (e.g. `if((i == 0) || (i == 6))`)?

Comment: Thanks so much both of you. Kinda embarrassing haha. Works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mistaken in the conditions.

You've used `=` (assignment operator) rather than comparison operator `==`.

Replace all the `=` in `if - else if` with `==`. Something like:

```
if((i == 0) || (i == 6))
     cout << x;
else if((i == 1) && (j == 5))
    cout << x;
else if((i == 2) && (j == 4))
    cout << x;
else if((i == 3) && (j == 3))
    cout << x;
else if((i == 4) && (j == 2))
    cout << x;
else if((i == 5) && (j == 1))
    cout << x;
else
    cout << ' ';
```

Notice that you don't need to use parenthesis for single-line containing conditions. The result will be:

```
XXXXXXX
     X
    X
   X
  X    
 X
XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use == for your comparisons, not =